# jQuery - parent selectors

Tags: jquery

I can't find out how exactly how parent selector works in jQuery.

```js
var test = $( "p:contains('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')" ).parentsUntil("span");
    
    
    test.css({ "border" : "1px solid red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
       <p>Title</p>
       <span>
        <p>Span</p>
        <div>
         <p>Div</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
       </span>
       <tr>
        <th>Xx</th>
        <td>YY</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
```

How to get border around span? My code doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is unclead. I can't understand what you want. Also your html isn't valid.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Browser handle this is various ways and you should correct this before working on your jQuery

Comment: Use `.closest("span")` instead of `parentsUntil("span")`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use .closest() instead, along with .parent():

```
var test = $( "p:contains('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')" ).parent().closest("span");
```

**UPDATE**

You can also keep using parentsUntil(), but add parent() for obvious reasons:

```
var test = $( "p:contains('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')" ).parentsUntil("span").parent();
```

But this won't work if the direct parent is of type "span," because parentsUntil excludes the current element.

Comment: Why if I change .closest("span") to .closest("table") it again not works?

Comment: @Karolina Ticha because your table is invalid (or at least it's not valid according to Chrome 51.0.2704.103). The paragraph and span should be wrapped in <tr> and <td> tags. Otherwise, they're automatically taken out of the table and it's as if the <table> tag is after them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [.parentsUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) will select all the parents in between the current element and the selector parent (excluding it)

- **selector** Type: Selector A string containing a selector expression to indicate where to stop matching ancestor elements.
- **filter** Type: Selector A string containing a selector expression to match elements against.

What you need is just [.parents('span')](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```js
var test = $( "p:contains('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')" ).parents("span");
    
    
    test.css({ "border" : "1px solid red", "display":"block"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
       <p>Title</p>
       <span>
        <p>Span</p>
        <div>
         <p>Div</p>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
       </span>
       <tr>
        <th>Xx</th>
        <td>YY</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
```